# SCORM 1.2 disable bookmarking via HTM?

Tags: scorm

we really need someones help as I am running out of ideas.

We use Oracle LMS and author via Cap5 using SCORM1.2.  The problem is as follows:

1: We point our LMS to the main HTM file on our website
2: We republish files direct to our website
3: Our Cap5 settings are for bookmarking
4: When we republish our Cap5 files after editing inevitably some of our users (we have about 7,000) are halfway through the learning object that we have just updated.
5: When they re-logon and try to go to the learning object they were trying to complete (the one we have just edited) - it just hangs on loading.  If they haven't done that object yet, everything is fine, if they have already done it, everything is fine.

My question is: firstly, is the hanging due to resuming/bookmarking and secondly, what can I do about it ?

I am quite happy to disable bookmarking (each elearning presentation is only around 50 slides) but will republishing this resolve the issue or do I have to edit any HTM files ?  I am not even too sure where bookmarking is stored (is it on our national LMS ?), if so, are these users totally knackered and will we have to re-enroll them ?

Any guidance would be much appreciated,

Bill

PS We are a National Health Service Hospital in the UK so your help would be helping a lot of people

PPS As you can tell, I am not a programmer so please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that just a change in/inavailability of bookmarking data would cause a hang. But we need you to gather some more info so folks can help you out.

Can you get any kind of debugging log out of the LMS for when the content is "hanging"? You need to know where and why the content is stopped. I also recommend using Firefox Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/), with Flashbug installed (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashbug/), and posting here all 3 things to this topic:

1. Any LMS deugging from during the hang
2. Any Firebug console errors logged during the hang
3. Any Flashbug console errors logged curing the hang

Also, have you talked to the LMS vendors about this? If there's a strong and replicable correlation between "user is taking sco when we update" and "user's sco hangs upon next load", then the vendor will know best under what conditions runtime errors related to SCORM launch and communication would occur.

Best of luck!